# Multiline texbox validation

Tags: validation, textbox

I want to validate maxlegnth of 5 characters in each row of the multiline textbox

Help me

Comment: What environment are we talking about? C#, Java, HTML, some database?

Comment: Winforms/Webapps ? Do you really expect help with that kind of a question? Voted to close as "Not a real question".

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example: A **TextArea** and span to show the validation results.

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" onblur="validateRows(this)"></textarea><br/>
<span id="validationResults" style="color:red"></span>
```

Here's the JavaScript code to validate each row:

```
function validateRows(e){
   var content = e.value.split("\n");
   for(var line in content){
     var charLength = content[line].length - 1;
     var lineNumber = parseInt(line) + 1;
     if(charLength > 5){
       document.getElementById("validationResults").innerHTML += "* line " 
                         + lineNumber + " has " + charLength 
                         + " characters" + "<br/>";
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: @rohith - I updated the code to include a "validation results" span instead of an alert. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

using split function(both in C# and Javascript) and then check length it.

```
var temp = [TextFromTextBox].split('\n');
foreach(var s in temp)
{
   if(!ValidateFunction(s))
   {
      // code for show exception
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
but iam not getting properly.
please send me detailed code in javascript or C#.

Answer (score 0):

This is a C# version. Can be used either in Web applications for server side validation or Windows applications. (In Web applications for client side validation, Jose Basilio's code is appropriate)

```
    public static bool HasMax5CharsPerLine(TextBox target)
    {
        foreach (string Line in target.Text.Split(new char[] {'\n'}))
            if (Line.Length > 5)
                return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, the Lines property is just for System.Windows.Forms.TextBox and is not available for System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.
[I have edited my post to work for both.]

Comment: Acutally iam looking for regular expression in which it shodn't allow more dan 5 characters per row